# Does PHP have a code-folding comment like C#'s #region?

Tags: php

Is there a region-like structure in php?

Or another structure for hiding and grouping codes

```
#region Region   
  
// Codes  
 
#endregion
```

Comment: No ..? #region is a feature in VisualStudio Code (maybe in some other IDEs as well), you can write PHP files with VSC, and use #region regions.

Comment: The term is "language feature" or "syntax" not "structure" .

Comment: It's often strongly discouraged to use regions, they often hide/lead to poorly designed code architecture. [Are #regions an antipattern or code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)

Comment: @Cid I would agree that it's easier to make classes too big and use this to keep it manageable, however it's still good for grouping functions or properties to the developers desire right?

Comment: @onlineThomas If you think you need to regroup methods or properties under a region, it means that you probably need a class instead

Comment: We may want to group within the class, but then we need to use regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm at least has this feature:

[image]

VSCode as well: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_folding-improvements

However it's not a language feature but an IDE feature.

Comment: thanks but when I add region, it adds text "region" to the page.

Comment: That's because you are adding the region inside the `HTML`. Place the region in a `PHP` block, e.g. `<?php #region foo ?>`

Comment: I already added it in php